# Drag and Drop in GWT

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I want to implement dragging functionality in my GWT application.
What i need exactly is when i drag a panel,other panel should also be dragged,
like dat of in touch screen application..

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the third cases of this page : 
http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/draggable/demo/MultiDragSample/MultiDragSample.html

???